# MySQL deadlock in simple table

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I'm having a deadlock issue that I don't get. Possibly it's because of the composite index `(idSite,timestamp)`. Maybe it's range locking on it?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `idLog` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idSite` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `secondsToNextLog` int(11) DEFAULT NULL 
  `gwRestarted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL 
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLog`),
  KEY `idSite` (`idSite`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I already removed a foreign key constraint from idSite, because foreign key constraints can be confusing in deadlocks.

I have four processes inserting data into this table (from a queue). The `show engine innodb status` shows these queries deadlocking:

```
INSERT INTO logs(idSite, timestamp, secondsToNextLog, gwRestarted) values ('5396', '1438764388', '900', '0')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO logs(idSite, timestamp, secondsToNextLog, gwRestarted) values ('5395', '1438764417', '60', '0')
```

I don't see how this could be deadlocking. The table is very simple and the two queries both are for a different idSite (I made sure of that in the queue processors). Moreover, the engine status shows that both transaction only use and lock one table, so I don't see how this can be a deadlock.

Shouldn't it be easily possible to insert as many rows at the same time as one wants, as long as `idSite` is different?

This is the complete deadlock info:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-08-05 09:11:38 2b6fcbf25700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 516854792, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 15503218, OS thread handle 0x2b6fcb273700, query id 3125430892 172.31.0.175 vrm_dev update
INSERT INTO logs(idSite, timestamp, secondsToNextLog, gwRestarted) values ('5396', '1438764388', '900', '0')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 135684 page no 15 n bits 776 index `idSite` of table `vrm_2012_dev`.`logs` trx id 516854792 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 516854776, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 15503217, OS thread handle 0x2b6fcbf25700, query id 3125430894 172.31.0.175 vrm_dev update
INSERT INTO logs(idSite, timestamp, secondsToNextLog, gwRestarted) values ('5395', '1438764417', '60', '0')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 135684 page no 15 n bits 776 index `idSite` of table `vrm_2012_dev`.`logs` trx id 516854776 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 135684 page no 15 n bits 776 index `idSite` of table `vrm_2012_dev`.`logs` trx id 516854776 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: Are those inserted idSite values (5395, 5396) bigger than anything already present in the table? `asc supremum` seems to hint that the "bigger-than-everything" gap is being locked by both those inserts, once to check it and second time to show the intention to insert - and a race occurs so the one locking it to check gets behind in signalling insert so you get a deadlock - it is not marked as a gap lock but this comment suggests it is possible not having a gap bit set https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/a2757a60a7527407d08115e44e889a25f22c96c6/storage/innobase/include/lock0priv.h#L292

Comment: How many rows are being inserted per second?  Can they be batched?  Do you have code in place to retry the insert on deadlock?  Is autocommit=ON?  Or are you using BEGIN..COMMIT?  Are other transactions touching the area near these rows?

Comment: I'm guessing that you probably resolved this issue between 2015 and now. Care to answer your own question and satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: @BigSmoke done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, my solution to an old question.

The [write intention lock docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-insert-intention-locks) say (emphasis mine, and yes, MySQL 5.7, because 8.0 didn't exist at the time):

> An insert intention lock is a type of gap lock set by INSERT
> operations prior to row insertion. This lock signals the intent to
> insert in such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the
> same index gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting
> at the same position within the gap. Suppose that there are index
> records with values of 4 and 7. Separate transactions that attempt to
> insert values of 5 and 6, respectively, each lock the gap between 4
> and 7 with insert intention locks **prior to obtaining the exclusive
> lock on the inserted row**.

The crucial part is the bold. In my case, my transaction was not done at this point, so it was holding a write intent **and** exclusive lock.

I suppose the fix is to finish your transaction after the insert, and not continue inserting. *My* fix was to (externally) serialize inserts, as it was a relatively infrequent operation. For instance, lacking direct concurrency control primitives like mutexes and rwlocks, you can designate a table with locks in it, and do `SELECT * FROM hack_locks WHERE id = <id_of_insert_lock_row> FOR UPDATE`. That way, once a transaction starts inserting, others can't.